# Prove $f(z)=p(z)/q(z)=\alpha$ has n solutions

Tags: complex-analysis, unique-factorization-domains, holomorphic-functions

Let $f(z)=p(z)/q(z)$ where $p(z),q(z)$ are polynomials without common roots and with $deg(q)\ne deg(p)$, $\alpha\in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$.

Let $n=\max\{\deg(p),\deg(q)\}$. Prove that $f(z)=\alpha$ has exactly $n$ solutions, counted with multiplicity.

How may I proceed with the proof?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can instead solve $p(z) - \alpha q(z) = 0$. This is a polynomial of degree...?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but is this true?  Take $p(z)=z-1, q(z)=z,$ and $\alpha = 1.$ Then $\frac{z-1}{z}=1$ has no solutions.

Comment: @MitchellSpector True. It is enough to require that $p,q$ have different degrees, however.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff -- yes, that I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Assume $\deg p \neq \deg q$)
With the fundamental theorem of algebra: $f(z) = \alpha$ becomes $$\alpha q(z) - p(z) = 0$$ $\alpha q(z) - p(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $\max\{n,m\}$, whence we have that many solutions.

Without FTA it can be done with Rouche's theorem: find $R$ large enough such that in a disk of radius $R$ centered at $0$, $$|\alpha q(z) - p(z)| \leq |z^{\max\{n,m\}}|$$ The trouble with this approach is that one may use the same argument to prove the fundamental theorem of algebra, so in a backwards way we are still using it. It can also be done using the argument principle, but we have the same issue as above if we're trying to avoid FTA.